# Save web page as "html only" (in Firefox) then highlight text permanently

Tags: webpage

I'd like to be able to save a copy of a web page locally ("HTML only") and then be able to highlight text on the page so that the highlights will be there after I close and reopen the HTML file later.

Any ideas how to do this in Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be HTML, you could always save it as a PDF file and highlight that way.

If it has to be HTML, then you will need to save it using the "Save Page As..." option in firefox and make sure "Web Page, complete" is selected and then save. Then you can highlight the page by using a WYSIWYG Editor or just adding the html yourself. There may be an add-on to have a WYSIWYG Editor in firefox as well.